# Loop through a PowerPoint presentation and replace certain keywords with text

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I was hoping to get some help. I have the following code that works on replacing text from a word documents with a certain word in excel. For example I have ClientName in a cell and the Cell next to it has John, so each time the word ClientName is found it is replaced with John and so on. Here is the code that works for word documents. Can it be altered to work for .pptx too?

```
Sub AutoContract()

Dim cell            As Range
Dim rng             As Range
Dim wdApp           As New Word.Application
Dim wdDoc           As Word.Document
Dim wdDoc2          As Word.Document
Dim FilePath        As String
Dim FilePath2       As String
Dim ending          As String
Dim rngPara         As Range
Dim Prompt          As String
Dim Filesave        As String
Dim FileSave2       As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Set wdApp = Nothing
FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path
FilePath2 = Left(FilePath, InStr(FilePath, "\Calculations") - 1)
Filename = "Filename.docx"
StrDoc = FilePath2 & "\Inputs" & "\" & Filename
Set wdDoc2 = wdApp.Documents.Open(StrDoc)



Set rngPara = Range("A1:Z1058").Find("Variable Parameters")
If rngPara Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Variable Parameters column was not found."
    GoTo ErrorHandler
  End If
Set rng = Range(rngPara, rngPara.End(xlDown))
wdApp.Visible = True
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = "" Then Exit For
    With wdDoc2.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Text = cell.Value
        .Replacement.Text = cell.Offset(0, 1)
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    Next
    
SaveAsName = Left(FilePath, InStr(FilePath, "\Calculations") - 1) & "\Outputs\" & Range("EmployName").Value & " " & Range("TodayDate").Value & " Contract" & ".docx"
wdDoc2.SaveAs2 SaveAsName

ErrorExit:
    Set wdApp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    If Err.Number = 5174 Then
    MsgBox "Please check the file name you specified is correct."
    Resume ErrorExit
    Else
        MsgBox "Error No: " & Err.Number & "; There is a problem"
        If Not wdApp Is Nothing Then
            wdApp.Quit False
        End If
        Resume ErrorExit
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code uses Word's function Find and Replace (ctrl+h), you could use the same trick with PowerPoint VBA but indirectly. You will have to loop through slides and shapes (and tables). This post could help you : https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/find-and-replace-in-powerpoint-using-excel-vba.1006141/

Comment: To save you from reinventing the wheel, here are 2 add-ins that already do mail merge to PowerPoint. The first is free, but simple: http://www.pptalchemy.co.uk/Simple_merge.html The second costs, but is more capable: http://www.pptools.com/merge/